# Chrome, Custom.css not always working

Tags: css, google-chrome

my Custom.css looks like this:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Roboto'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'Ubuntu'; src: local('Arial'); }
```

in case of Ubuntu it works
in case of Roboto it does not work

it may be specific to this site
http://www.origo.hu/techbazis/20130908-belelat-a-mobilokba-az-amerikai-nemzetbiztonsag.html

near the bottom in comment section, the fonts does not change

Comment: You are swapping Roboto and Ubuntu with locally installed Arial. Is that what you want?

Comment: seems like your css is empty? http://static.origos.hu/s/201309096/css/techbazis/custom.css

Comment: Maybe something went wrong when trying to upload the css file. If you have "Ubuntu" installed under the same name, but "Roboto" under another name, it would explain why it only shows Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

it is becuse Roboto is downloaded with the site, and for some reason locally defined Custom.css file can not override it

your have to block *.woff and *.ttf